# React, localhost refused to connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localhost

I am trying to create a basic application that I able to serve as a movie database. Im following a tutorial on YouTube ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jc9_Bqzy2YQ&t=243s)) (I have reached 5:22 in the video)

Im stuck banging my head against the wall because I cannot get the app to run in a chrome browser. At the current stage all I should see is a blank white screen.

Instead when I run it I see chrome saying that "this site can't be reached" and "local host refused to connect"

I have tried EVERY possible solution I could find on the internet. These are a notable few:

1. Disabling computer firewall
2. changing localhost:8080 to localhost:3000

I am running MacOS and the latest version of react and visual studio code.
I've attached a few images for your reference.

[Visual Studio Code launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcRqb.png)
[Chrome Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOQOh.png)

Comment: are you sure your app is running? You need to run npm start in terminal. When app starts it automatically takes you to the app

Comment: I tried this but the terminal displays "failed to compile" and the web browser says "failed to compile Module not found: Can't resolve './index.css' in '/Users/********/Documents/Projects/Coding/React/movie-app/src'"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app is running as told in comment. If you have not defined "start" in your package.json file, then try to run
`node app.js` and verify again localhost:3000.

Comment: OP is using CRA so `start` _will_ be defined in the scripts section of `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the compile errors:
So I figured out the main problem. I had deleted the files index.css and reportWebVitals from my react app. I did this because the YouTube tutorial had done this as well, I assume it was to make it a bit cleaner. Upon creating a new react app I was able to follow each step of the process but this time I made sure keep the index.css and reportWebVitals files and it worked. Not sure why the app ran in the YouTube tutorial and not for me.

Solution to the localhost not connecting:
I followed the suggestions of running it using nom start which got the local host to connect. I was earlier doing it through visual studio code's "start debugging" option.

Comment: Your app didn't run Because in the tutorial they have removed the index.css import from index.js. you haven't

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Out of blue Firefox would not connect to 127.0.0.1 and of course its alias localhost. The problem has been there since forever without proper resolution.
This is what I found out...
Firefox would 'upgrade' 127.0.0.1 to https://127.0.0.1 and fail to connect
but setting explicitely http://127.0.0.1 woule get connection. To not have to do that every time it occurs go to Firefox privacy settings and set

```
        **Enable HTTPS-Only Mode in all windows**
```

so that Firefox 'upgrades' are not haphazard and life seems to be good again.

Answer (score 0):

I have just run into the same problem. I have solved the problem by removing index.css import in the App.js not index.js. But at least Charchit help guided me to do that. Thanks Charchit and all those volunteered to help.